# xmlns="" is unwantedly being added

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

Following is my XML request, I am a beginner.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://www.juniper.es/webservice/2007/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<HotelAvail>
<HotelAvailRQ Version="1.1" Language="en">
<Login Email="user@mydomain.com" Password="pass" />
<Paxes>
<Pax IdPax="1">
<Age>8</Age>
</Pax> 
</Paxes> 
<HotelRequest> 
<SearchSegmentsHotels> 
<SearchSegmentHotels Start="2013-08-20" End="2013-08-22" DestinationZone="1953"/> 
<CountryOfResidence>ES</CountryOfResidence> 
<Boards> 
<Board Type="AD"/> 
</Boards> 
</SearchSegmentsHotels> 
<RelPaxesDist> 
<RelPaxDist> 
<RelPaxes> 
<RelPax IdPax="1"/> 
</RelPaxes> 
</RelPaxDist> 
</HotelRequest> 
<AdvancedOptions> 
<ShowHotelInfo>true</ShowHotelInfo> 
</AdvancedOptions> 
</HotelAvailRQ> 
</HotelAvail> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to create c# request for this but i am getting xmlns="" in Hotelavail tag which i do not want.

```
//Declaration
          const string SOAPENV_NS = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
          const string WKSP_NS = "http://www.juniper.es/webservice/2007/";
          XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = XMLDoc1.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", null);
            //root
            XMLsoapenv = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("soapenv", "Envelope", SOAPENV_NS);
            XMLsoapenv.SetAttribute("xmlns:soapenv", SOAPENV_NS);
            XMLsoapenv.SetAttribute("xmlns", WKSP_NS);
            //XMLDoc1.AppendChild(XMLsoapenv);
            //header
            XMLsoapenvHeader = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("soapenv", "Header", SOAPENV_NS);
            XMLsoapenv.AppendChild(XMLsoapenvHeader);
            XMLsoapenvBody = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("soapenv", "Body", SOAPENV_NS);
            XMLsoapenv.AppendChild(XMLsoapenvBody);
            //XMLDoc1.AppendChild(XMLsoapenv);
            XMLHotelAvail = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("HotelAvail");
            XMLHotelAvailRQ = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("HotelAvailRQ");
            XMLHotelAvailRQ.SetAttribute("Version", "1.1");
            XMLHotelAvailRQ.SetAttribute("Language", language1);
            XMLLogin = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("Login");
            XMLLogin.SetAttribute("Email", email);
            XMLLogin.SetAttribute("Password", password);
            XMLHotelAvailRQ.AppendChild(XMLLogin);
            XMLPaxes = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("Paxes");
            XMLPaxFirstChild = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("Pax");
            XMLPaxFirstChild.SetAttribute("IdPax", "1");
            XMLPaxFirstChild.SetAttribute("Age", searchCriteria.FirstChild);
            XMLPaxes.AppendChild(XMLPaxFirstChild);
            XMLHotelAvailRQ.AppendChild(XMLPaxes);
            XMLHotelRequest = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("HotelRequest");
            XMLSearchSegmentsHotels = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("SearchSegmentsHotels");
            XMLSearchSegmentHotels = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("SearchSegmentHotels");
            XMLSearchSegmentHotels.SetAttribute("Start", searchCriteria.CheckInDate);
            XMLSearchSegmentHotels.SetAttribute("End", searchCriteria.CheckOutDate);
            XMLSearchSegmentHotels.SetAttribute("DestinationZone", "628");
            XMLCountryOfResidence = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("CountryOfResidence", searchCriteria.Country);
            XMLSearchSegmentHotels.AppendChild(XMLCountryOfResidence);
            XMLSearchSegmentsHotels.AppendChild(XMLSearchSegmentHotels);
            XMLHotelRequest.AppendChild(XMLSearchSegmentsHotels);
            XMLRelPaxesDist = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("RelPaxesDist");
            XMLRelPaxDist = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("RelPaxDist");
            XMLRelPaxes = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("RelPaxes");
            XMLRelPax = XMLDoc1.CreateElement("RelPax");
            XMLRelPax.SetAttribute("IdPax", "1");
            XMLRelPaxes.AppendChild(XMLRelPax);
            XMLRelPaxDist.AppendChild(XMLRelPaxes);
            XMLRelPaxesDist.AppendChild(XMLRelPaxDist);
            XMLHotelRequest.AppendChild(XMLRelPaxesDist);
            XMLHotelAvailRQ.AppendChild(XMLHotelRequest);
            XMLHotelAvail.AppendChild(XMLHotelAvailRQ);
            XMLsoapenv.AppendChild(XMLHotelAvail);
            //XMLsoapenvBody.AppendChild(XMLHotelAvail);
            //XMLsoapenv.AppendChild(XMLsoapenvBody);
            XMLDoc1.AppendChild(XMLsoapenv);
```

I have tried giving "SOAPENV_NS" in Hotelavail tag as I read it somewhere so xmlns="" wouldn't be added but no use I get the url as well.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reduce this to a [mcve] - I'm sure you don't need *this* much XML or code in order to represent the problem. Then please make sure you format your code as readably as possible - use the preview to see what your post will look like before posting it.

Comment: (It's not clear what this has to do with XSLT or xmlhttprequest, either - and I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML rather than the old `XmlDocument` API, if you possibly can.)

Comment: Just  pass the correct namespace into the `CreateElement` call and you should be set

Comment: I did it, I added the same namespace into the 'CreateElement' but it added the URLs ass well

like:  xmlns = "URL" 
in every element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're implicitly creating `HotelAvail` and all its children with an empty namespace (as you don't specify one in your calls to `CreateElement`).

The 'default' namespace is defined in the root of your XML by `xmlns="http://www.juniper.es/webservice/2007/"`.

Change your `CreateElement` calls for `HotelAvail` and children to:

```
XMLDoc1.CreateElement("HotelAvail", WKSP_NS);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oWNdXp) for a working demo.

As an aside, I'd agree with Jon Skeet that you should probably investigate LINQ to XML rather than using the old `XmlDocument` API. It's much nicer to work with.